# How do I read data from a database using LINQ to SQL in VB using an IQueryable?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am fairly new to visual basic and know only a little about LINQ and SQL. I know how to select items from an array with LINQ, but what I can't figure out how to do is access a database using an IQueryable. I connected the database to my project, added two classes from the database to the "LINQ to SQL" .dbml file and saved it. In my programming assignment, I am not supposed to create a data source (table thing) to display the data, but update my own interface manually. In order to do it, I was told to instantiate this:

```
Private dogs As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Dog)
```

(Dog is a class that I added to my .dbml file from the database file)

Also, I am told it involves using a method

```
.AsEnumerable.ElementAt(index As Integer)
```

And somehow I am supposed to load database data from/using this. Help please if you can. I got screwed over by my professors as our online assignment program was down the whole thanksgiving break so I'm here doing this at the last minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an instance of your data context class (which has the same name as your dbml + "DataContext"). Let's say it is AnimalsDataContext:

```
using (var context = new AnimalsDataContext())
{
    var dogs = context.Dogs;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain the part in the brackets a little more? What does "var dogs = context.Dogs" do exactly? Also, where does IQueryable come in?

Comment: context.Dogs *is* an `IQueryable`.

Comment: Only now I realise I jumped to C# without thinking. I assume you'll figure out how to do it in VB ;).

Comment: Yes I did figure it out. One more question. I have private instance variables as IQueryable that I set to the context.Dogs. I notice I can only call their methods within the bracketed part of Using which I have in my form load method. If I do dogs.asEnumerable.elementAt(0).Name outside Using I get a "Cannot access disposed variable" error." Would it be bad to create an instance variable as DataContext?

Comment: In fact this is a whole new chapter. Do some research on datacontext lifetime (or lifecycle) management. In short: you can convert the `IQueryable` to e.g. a list while the datacontext is alive and then use the list anywhere else. Not an IEnumerable, because it defers execution of the query.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the help. I'd upvote but I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: @GertArnold you could make the module level variable IEnumerable IF you call .GetEnumerator on it before the context goes out of scope. Calling .ToList/ToArray on the IQueryable starts by calling .GetEnumerator under the covers so that covers those secnarios.

Comment: @JimWooley, Sure, but outside the scope of the DataContext an IEnumerable could be enumerated again, that's why I'd prefer to store results in a list/collection.